# Creating separate linear model for every combination(/interaction) of factors

Tags: r, plyr, linear-regression, interaction, categorical-data

I'm trying to do a simple linear regression on my data frame that looks something like what follows. The actual data set has more factors and more predictors (x's) all trying to predict y.

```
f1 f2 x y
x  a  1 3.3
x  a  2 3.2
x  a  3 3.04
x  b  1 4.5
x  b  2 4.9
x  b  3 8
y  a  1 20.1
y  a  2 20.3
y  a  3 21.9
y  b  1 101.2
y  b  2 201.8
y  b  3 332.8
```

Notice, for every combination of f1 & f2 the trends vary. What I want to do is build a lm model for each combination of f1 & f2, store it in some kind of list and then when I call predict, I should be able to use the appropriate model and predict y based on x. I think I should use ldply to create a list of models, as shown below

```
lm.model.list = ldply(x,.(f1,f2),function(x) {
 fit = lm(x$y ~ x$x)
 return(fit)
 }
```

This gives an error,

```
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

Also, assume I get it all into a list, how do I work with predict after that?

edit: I realize I could use indicator variables for the factors in the modelling itself, but I want to avoid this.

Comment: I don't understand why you would fit a separate model to each subset of your data. Isn't that what interaction terms are for?

Comment: Interaction between two predictors A & B would model if A & B combined is different from A and B combined linearly. Also, I would like to extend learnings from here for other models, say neural networks (eg)

Comment: Maybe `dlply` rather than `ldply`?

Comment: Yes, dlply typo in code. But how do I deal with predict?

Comment: Read about [interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics)) of factors. Separate models is generally not the way to go; if you believe there is association of factors/correlation of  or nonlinear behavior of response variable, then look into those. e.g. `I(x**2)` and `sqrt(x)` terms.  But in this case, you can see the x:b case is nonlinear: `(1,4.5), (2,4.9), (3,8)`. The (3,8) is either severely nonlinear or an anomaly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is just:

```
fit <- lm(y ~ x+ f1*f2, data=dfrm)
```

This will give a different prediction for each level of the interaction of f1 with f2. It's just one model but could be "queried" for predictions with the `predict` function using any desired combo of f1 and f2. You should look at ?formula and spend some time understanding how linear models get interpreted.

Comment: But look at the x:b case, it's severely nonlinear: `(1,4.5), (2,4.9), (3,8)`. The (3,8) is either severely nonlinear or an anomaly

Comment: The model does not have an x:b term and since there is no b column, it's not clear what is being asked. Worrying about single point is a sign not to little data.

Comment: The x.b case clearly either has an anomaly at `(3,8)` or else involves a very sharp nonlinearity to fit to 4.5,4.9,**8** (in whch case they do need separate models).